# Full comunication with console using C#

Tags: c#, bots, telegram

I'm developing a programm to control a CMD in my VPS using C# and a Telegram bot.
The connection between the Telegram bot and programm works great, so It's not a problem.
I want to write commands from my Telegram bot in the same cmd window.
To send the string commands to the cmd I use:

```
public static void Trythis(Message comando)
    {
        Process p = new Process();
        ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
        info.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        info.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        info.UseShellExecute = false;
        String output = String.Empty;
        p.StartInfo = info;
        p.Start();

        using (StreamWriter sw = p.StandardInput)
        {
            if (sw.BaseStream.CanWrite)
            {
                sw.WriteLine(comando.Text);

            }
        }
        using (StreamReader streamReader = p.StandardOutput)
        {
            output = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            Bot.SendTextMessageAsync(comando.Chat.Id, output);
        }



    }
}
```

But I get invalidOperationException in this part:

```
        using (StreamReader streamReader = p.StandardOutput)
        {
            output = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            Bot.SendTextMessageAsync(comando.Chat.Id, output);
        }
```

Comment: Please make a [mcve], run it, and give us the full stack trace from that -- not just the exception type, but the message and line it occurs on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput(v=vs.110).aspx):

> **InvalidOperationException**.
>
> The StandardOutput stream has not been defined for redirection; ensure ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput is set to true and ProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute is set to false.
>
> (or)
>
> The StandardOutput stream has been opened for asynchronous read operations with BeginOutputReadLine.

I think you need to add this line to the beginning:

```
info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked :)

Answer (score 0):

The end of a `using` block calls `Dispose()` on the wrapped object... after the first call, you're *closing and disposing your stream*.